# Using delegate - StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, delegates, user-controls

I have `Form1` with `UserControl1` witch shows me an overview of data in a `DataGridView`. On this `UserControl` I use the `ContexMenu` to open another Form (Form2) also with an `UserControl` to add data.

If I close `Form2` I want to do an action on my `Form1`.

Usually this works fine with the following way but at the moment I only get a `StackOverflowException` cause the `MessageBox` is shown up all the time.

So what is wrong?

Form1 - binding uc1

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ShowOverview();
        }
     void ShowOverview()
        {
            uc1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.tabPageOverview.Controls.Add(uc1);
        }
....
```

uc1 - context menu to open Form2 and delegate action

```
...
 private void dataGridView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                contextMenu.Show(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
            }
        }
        private void newItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form fc = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
            if (fc != null)
                fc.Close();

            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.Callback = new Form2.ItemDelegate(this.ShowItems);
            f.Show();
        }
        void ShowItems()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST");
        }
...
```

Form2 with uc2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public delegate void ItemDelegate();
        public ItemDelegate Callback;

        ucItem uc = new ucItem(null);

        public F_Einkaufsartikel_Hinterlegen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.StyleForm();

            ShowUserControl2();

        }
        void ShowUserControl2()
        {
            uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(uc);
        }
     


private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Callback();
            ((Form)this.TopLevelControl).Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Looking at your stack trace should give you some useful hints.